# Screen Sharing With goinstant

Tags: javascript, php, goinstant, goinstant-platform

Is it possible to implement the screen sharing of my website to another guest user using the API provided by the GOINSTANT.

I have done some examples which have been provided in the website to show the form widget and sharing the same to the another user.

But my requirement is not a form widget.I wold like to share the screen and move over from one page to another page in my website which should reflect to the other user.

If there is a possibility can you please provide me the example to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout GoInstant's Collaboration Bundle: https://developers.goinstant.com/beta/widgets/collaboration_bundle.html

The Collaboration Bundle will provide a co-browse ("screenshare") like experience on your website. It includes the Form, User List, Scroll, and Click widgets in a single bundle, along with URL following and invite a friend features.